# For loop broken?

Tags: debugging, loop

This is a pseudo code from my LED cube project

```
void loop(){
  //switch( map(constrain(analogRead(pt),10,1020),10,1020,1,4));  - for select pattern
  //show(1);
 for(lp=128;lp>=1;lp = lp/2){
  runfor(1000,lp,1,0,0,0,0);
  //Serial.println("HI");
 }
}

void runfor(short mills,byte a,byte b,byte c,byte d,byte e,byte f){
  timer = millis();
  Serial.println(a);
  while((millis()-timer)<=mills){
    light_L1(a,b);
    //light_L2(c,d);
    //light_L3(e,f);
  }
}
```

the variable 'lp' here never changes its value and remains 128

Why is this?

Comment: What makes you believe `lp` does not change?

Comment: Tested using serial.println, second line in the runfor()

Comment: I run it. no surprise. the value changes as expected.

Comment: @Juraj Is this a problem with my chip or IDE then?

Comment: no. it is a problem of your snippet. it makes something else like the sketch from which you extracted it and didn't test

Comment: So maybe another function is affecting it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82257/discussion-between-a-shetye-and-juraj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't ever use a global variable for `for` loop.**

You use the same variable in functions `for` loops which count down to zero. If `lp` is zero `for` loop in `loop()` ends and new `loop()` starts.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran your code as you presented it in the chat, lp stayed at 128. When I commented-out the "light_L1()" call in "runfor()", lp decremented by 1/2 its value per step as you would expect. The issue is that lp is global and therefore, accessible by any other function. One of your lower functions is resetting it.

Comment: so I induced the asker to post the code and the problem showed itself. but you didn't explain why the value jumps to 128

Comment: The value changes because one of the lower functions changes it. Why didn't I continue to debug it down to the last detail? 1) To not steal a potential learning experience from the OP; and 2) because it really doesn't matter to the question: "the variable 'lp' here never changes its value and remains 128  Why is this?". I pointed the overall problem - modification of a global from multiple places in the code. The rest is up the OP, who can ask for further help if s/he wants it.